# How to stop tracking after coming back to the same activity

Tags: android, timer, latitude-longitude

I have a tracking application which is showing longitude and latitude.

I have a screen which have 3 buttons showlocation , start tracking and stop tracking. Now what i want is that the tracking will remain continue until i click the stop button. Now thing is when i stays on the same activity, the start tracking and stop tracking is working fine but when i only click the start tracking button and go back to other activities and then come back to that particular activity and clicking the stop button the activity is crashing and if i click start tracking button the tracking starts again which means the timer which i executed is working 2 times.

So i want 2 solutions:
1. When the one timer is working on the click of button to other timer will not start on again clicking the start button.
2. And when i come back to the activity and click the stop button the timer should stop.

Here is my code

```
public class GPSTrackingActivity extends Activity {

Timer timer;
TimerTask timerTask;   
final Handler handler = new Handler();

// GPSTracker class
GPStracker gps;
double longitude, latitude;
Button showLocation1,timerstopped,starttimer;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_gpstracking);
 showLocation1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showlocation1);

 // show location button click event
 showLocation1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {        
            // create class object
            // create class object
            gps = new GPStracker(GPSTrackingActivity.this);

            // check if GPS enabled     
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                // \n is for new line
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
            }else{
                // can't get location
                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }
        }
    });

 starttimer =(Button) findViewById(R.id.starttimer);

 // stop showing location button click event
 starttimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {                

            // create class object
            startTimer();
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your tracking is now started " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          

            }
    });



 timerstopped =(Button) findViewById(R.id.timerstopped);

 // stop showing location button click event
 timerstopped.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            timer.cancel();
            timerTask.cancel(); 
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your tracking is now stopped " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          

            }
    });

}




public void startTimer() {

            //set a new Timer       
          timer = new Timer();

          //initialize the TimerTask's job      
          gpsmethod();      

            //schedule the timer, after the first 1000ms the TimerTask will run every min

            timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 10000); //

        }


public void gpsmethod() {
    timerTask=new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    GPStracker gps = new GPStracker(GPSTrackingActivity.this);
                    //call your function for getting lat n lon
                     double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                   double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }; 
}
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the Activity life cycle? http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html You could, for instance, override onPause() and call the stop timer function there. onPause() will be called when the activity is no longer in the view.

Comment: You should use logs to print values and check your values in activity